# Blue lines when using a high resolution

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card, resolution, gpu

I bought a new computer screen of 2560x1440, however, using any resolution higher than 1920x1080 makes the screen very blue, vertical lines. As if every odd pixel on the x-axis is not displayed and every even pixel has a blue tint.

This is strange, my old screen was 1920x1200 and worked fine. I just updated my GPU driver (I have a GTX 260) but no success.

What could be the cause? Power shortage? GPU faulty? Driver issue? Windows 7...?

Comment: It could be a number of things. How are you connecting to the monitor; Dual Link DVI, HDMI, or Display Port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never knew there are different types of DVI cables. I plugged in the DVI cable from my old monitor and assumed it to work, but there are about 6 pins missing. Just connected the "dual-link" DVI cable that was accompanied with the new monitor, and it works. Wow what a huge amount of pixels!